# How much storage do I need to save a month's worth of video recording?

Tags: video, cctv, surveillance, home-surveillance

I'm planning to set up a video surveillance system in our house. The model for the cameras is [Hikvision](http://www.hikvision.com/us/Products_1_10534_i7722.html) 4MP Camera. I want to record continuously for 30 days at 4MP. How much storage does this setup need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to record continuously for 30 days at 4MP. How much storage
>   does this setup need?

You will need around 953 GB in order to store 720 hour, @20FPS with a resolution of 2688x1520 encoded with H.264

> - BluRay H.264 (1080p25 = 56 Mbps)    953 GB
> - BluRay H.264 (1080p25 = 56 Mbps)    88.3 Mbps   = 11 MB/s

Source: [Video filesize calculator](https://toolstud.io/video/filesize.php?imagewidth=2688&imageheight=1520&framerate=20&timeduration=720&timeunit=hours)

[Camera Specifications](http://www.hikvision.com/us/Products_1_10534_i7722.html):

> - Frame Rate: 20 fps (2688 × 1520), 30 fps (1920 × 1080, 1280 × 720)
> - Video Compression:  H.264/MJPEG/H.264+
> - Video bit rate: 32Kbps~16Mbps

Comment: The only problem with this estimation is that it is indicating a video bit rate that far exceeds the camera specifications.  So you are likely going to need far less then 953 GB, but the calculator I used, is limited in it's calculations.  The calculations assume you are recording at 2688x1520 at 25 fps, but you are actually recording at at 20 fps, will make a considerable difference in the overall size.  The calculations also assume you are recording at that resolution.  Since you didn't provide specifics I made an educated assumption.